# Connect to Sqlite DB in Azure File Share

Tags: azure, sqlite, fileshare

Anyone have an idea how to read/write in Sqlite db stored in the azure file share. I'm using C# and EF provider to work with Sqlite's db. The problem is that the EF provider needs a file path to connect with the db; I know mounting the file share as a disk will work but I'm looking for a different approach since the web app that is going to use the DB will be hosted in azure as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you tried to convert absoluteurl to relative path. It may be possible to get it

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.